# Calculate rank of each month in Excel

Tags: macos, microsoft-excel, mac, worksheet-function

I'm using Excel for Mac. I have a spreadsheet with scores for each month:

[image]

I need a function that ranks the scores for each month. For example, for "Jan" the function should rank the score of 8 as 1 and the score of 68 as 2. I have manually inserted what the function should output in the rank column. Can anyone provide such a function?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use COUNTIFS()

```
=COUNTIFS(A:A,A2,B:B,"<"&B2)+1
```

This counts how many match the month and are less than the value and adds `1` to it.  If it is the lowest then the countifs will return `0` so we add `1` to it to get the 1st.

[image]